# iOS UILabel equivalent in Android?

Tags: android, ios, android-layout, uilabel

What is `UILabel`'s equivalent ui component in Android?
(`UILabel` is a component in Swift that shows text)

I see many options, what is the difference?

[image]

Comment: What is UILabel? And what does not match with Android Views?

Comment: As for as I know about Android Plain TextView is the equivalent of UILabel.

Comment: @János have you tried using all of these TextView's in one xml and figure out the differences between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this [article](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/), `UILabel` is a UI component that is used for showing text in an application. Thus, `TextView` component is the equivalent in Android.

Answer (score 5):

All are TextView's, you can use any of the TextView (UILabel's equivalent ui component) based on your requirement, ex small, large etc.

Answer (score 1):

All TextViews are used as UILabel in android but the difference is their standard sizes (small ,medium ,Large) but you can also set their sizes and color .

Answer (score 1):

TextView is the equivalent to Swift's UILabel.

The main difference between the options you are showing is the default text size. TextView does not have any, so it's more likely to UILabel